# problem with passing style to style props

Tags: reactjs

i have a component and i want to pass my custom style to it throughout style property
but i got syntax error for ( `,` ) between each piece
the component

```
  <NeuButton
          width='60%'
          height='40px'
          style={{}}
```

and what i want to add to style is

```
"box-shadow": 0px 0px 0px #b6c0ca, 0px 0px 0px #ffffff, inset 5px 6px 4px #b6c0ca, inset 0px 0px 6px #ffffff,
```

it is for shadow of the component in each side

Comment: Should be `style={{boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px #b6c0ca, 0px 0px 0px #ffffff, inset 5px 6px 4px #b6c0ca, inset 0px 0px 6px #ffffff"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the jss style

```
<NeuButton 
     style={{ boxShadow: " 0px 0px 0px #b6c0ca, 0px 0px 0px #ffffff, inset 5px 6px 4px #b6c0ca, inset 0px 0px 6px #ffffff" }}
>
  Content here

</NeuButton>
```

Comment: how can i have it in `if` statement like when somethin was equal by true then show this if not ,it would be the defualt

Comment: ```style={{ boxShadow: booleanValue ? " 0px 0px 0px #b6c0ca, 0px 0px 0px #ffffff, inset 5px 6px 4px #b6c0ca, inset 0px 0px 6px #ffffff" : "" }}```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the value in quotes, and use boxShadow instead of "box-shadow" (using the javascript naming convention)

```
boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px #b6c0ca, 0px 0px 0px #ffffff, inset 5px 6px 4px #b6c0ca, inset 0px 0px 6px #ffffff`
```

Why you need to do that ? here an example

```
let height = 0;
//...
style={{width: 0, height}}
```

How to tell here if `width: 0, 1` or `width: 0` and `height:0` ? you can't, and thats why the css property that has many attribute should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: can i use it in` if` statement?

Comment: in if statement like when somethin was equal by true then show this if not ,it would be the default ,means don't use it at all if it was false

Comment: yes, you can, use this style={{color: test ? 'red':'blue' }} where test is true or false